# СheckBox menu Java

Tags: java, android, checkbox, menu

Здравствуйте). Пишу мобильное приложение android. Нужен `CheckBox` в шапке у меню, так как такого элемента как обычный `CheckBox` там нет, добавил item и в его настройках включил `checkable`, как теперь написать обработчик событий? Обработчик как у обычного `CheckBox` не подходит. Не работает).
мой не рабочий код:

```
if (id == R.id.action_online) {
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
            final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.action_online);
            checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
                        textView.setText("WTF!!!");
                    } else {
                        textView.setText("WTF!!!");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

пытался так же вместо обычного `CheckBox` написать `CheckedTextView`, не работает, а у `Checkable` вообще нет атрибута `setOnClickListener`.Помогите пожалуйста))
Пытался написать как в этих статьях:
1) http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/checkbox.php
2) https://metanit.com/java/android/4.3.php

Comment: Не понятно. У вас `CheckBox| сейчас?

Answer (score 0):

Надо слушать другой листенер:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            //blah-blah
       }
   }
);
```

Comment: К сожалению это не работает(( Приложение вылетает :((

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение)

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

        if (id == R.id.action_online) {
            if (item.isChecked()){
                textView.setText("text true!");
                item.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                textView.setText("text false!");
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Вы же хотели слушатель, а здесь просто проверка состояния чекбокса - налицо неверная формулировка вопроса.